# Find the equation of the focal chord of the ellipse

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> Find the equation of the focal chord of the
> ellipse $3x^2 + 4y^2 = 48$ , whose length is 7.

I found that one of the foci of the ellipse is (2; 0). If I express the equation of the line L that is requested as L: y = mx + b, and replace the coordinates of the point (2; 0), I obtain b = -2m. With this we have L: y = m (x-2). I only need the slope m to solve the problem, but I don't know how to get it. Tried plugging into ellipse equation but got nowhere.

Comment: *The* focus … Only one, really?

Comment: I was referring to only one of the foci actually. I misspelled that part, sorry about that. I only worked with one of the foci because by obtaining the equation of one of the lines that satisfies the condition, I can obtain the other by symmetry.

Comment: @Nicj: Don't be surry, I was just kidding ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation of the ellipse in standard form is

$\dfrac{x^2}{16} + \dfrac{y^2}{12} = 1 $

i.e. $a^2 = 16 , b^2 = 12 $

So the eccentricity is $e = \sqrt{1 - \dfrac{12}{16}} = \dfrac{1}{2}$.

Hence the foci are at $(- a e, 0 )$ and $(a e, 0)$, i.e. at $(-2, 0)$ and $(2, 0)$.

Now pass a line making an angle $\theta $ with the positive $x$ axis, through the right focus, then its parameteric equation is

$ p(t) = (2, 0) + t (\cos \theta , \sin \theta)$

Place this point on the ellipse, then

$(2 + t \cos \theta)^2 / 16 + (t \sin \theta)^2/12 = 1$

Expanding we get a quadratic equation in $t$ as follows

$ a_2 t^2 + a_1 t + a_0 = 0 $

Where $a_2 = \dfrac{\cos^2 \theta}{16} + \dfrac{\sin^2 \theta } { 12 }, a_1 = \dfrac{1}{4} \cos \theta , a_0 = -\dfrac{3}{4} $

The discriminant is

$D= a_1^2 - 4 a_2 a_0 = \dfrac{1}{4}$

Thus the difference in the two solutions is

$\Delta t = \dfrac{\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{4}}}{ a_2 }  = 7 $

Hence,

$\dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{7}{16} \cos^2 \theta +\dfrac{7}{12} \sin^2 \theta $

Using $\cos^2 \theta = \dfrac{1}{2}(1 + \cos 2 \theta) $, and $ \sin^2 \theta = \dfrac{1}{2} (1 - \cos 2 \theta )$, the above equation becomes,

$\dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{49}{96} - \dfrac{7}{96} \cos 2 \theta $

which has the solutions

$ \theta = \pm \dfrac{1}{2}\cos^{-1} \dfrac{1}{7} $

Now the equation of the focal chord is fully known.